# Salt-stack test.ping does not work on nodegroup with single minion

Tags: salt-stack

I have declared the following nodegroups

```
nodegroups:
   dev: 'mint'
```

Pinging individually works but pinging the nodegroup does not

```
root@salt:~# salt mint test.ping
mint:
    True
root@salt:~# salt -N dev test.ping
mint:
    Minion did not return. [Not connected]
root@salt:~# salt mint test.ping
mint:
    True
```

Pinging oher nodegroups (which have multiple hosts) works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to make that a one item list. This works for me:

```
nodegroups:
   dev: 'L@mint'
```